# Janusgraph(GremlinServer) Import improve performance

Tags: performance, import, cassandra, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I'm trying to import graph data of 1GB (consists of ~100k vertices, 3.6 million edges) which is **gryo** format. I tried to import through gremlin-client, I'm getting the following error:

> gremlin>
> graph.io(IoCore.gryo()).readGraph('janusgraph_dump_2020_09_30_local.gryo')
> GC overhead limit exceeded Type ':help' or ':h' for help. Display
> stack trace? [yN]y java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit
> exceeded at
> org.cliffc.high_scale_lib.NonBlockingHashMapLong$CHM.(NonBlockingHashMapLong.java:471)
> at
> org.cliffc.high_scale_lib.NonBlockingHashMapLong.initialize(NonBlockingHashMapLong.java:241)

Gremlin-Server, Cassandra details as follows:

Gremlin-Server:

Janusgraph Version: 0.5.2
Gremlin Version: 3.4.6

```
Heap: JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms4G -Xmx4G …
// gremlin conf
threadPoolWorker: 8
gremlinPool: 16
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 90000
// cql props
query.batch=true
```

Cassandra is in Cluster with 3 nodes

Cassandra version: 3.11.0

Node1: RAM: 8GB, Cassandra Heap: 1GB (-Xms1G -Xmx1G)
Node2: RAM: 8GB, Cassandra Heap: 4GB (-Xms4G -Xmx4G)
Node3: RAM: 8GB, Cassandra Heap: 4GB (-Xms4G -Xmx4G)

Each node has installed with Gremlin-Server (Load Balancer for clients). But we are *executing gremlin queries in Node1*.

Can someone help me on the following:

**What do I need to do import(any configuration changes) ?**

**>>> What is the best way to export/import huge data into Janusgraph(Gremlin-Server)?** *(I need answer for this)*

**Is there any way I can export the data in chunks and import in chunks ?**

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've increased Node1, Gremlin-Server Heap to 2GB. Import query response is *cancelled*. Perhaps, for both Gremlin and Cassandra, RAM allocation is not sufficient. That's why I've kept it to 1GB, so that the query will be executed.

Considering huge data (billions of vertices/edges), this is very less, hope 8GB RAM and 2/4 core would be sufficient for each node in cluster.

Comment: increase heap... to at least 3Gb

Comment: I've increased to 2GB, then query got cancelled(Response). I forgot to mention.

Comment: Cassandra is really not designed to run in so low heap environments... You can also tun JVM GC for low heap sizes...

Comment: I also have configured in such way where gremlin will connect to only other two Cassandra which have 4GB heap but of no use

Comment: Janus will use all Cassandra nodes in the cluster, because what you're configured is initial contact points...

Comment: I've configured the other two nodes as initial contact points (node2, node3)

Comment: add `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` to gremlin Java options...

Comment: Okay, will add and update the status

Comment: I've added but of no use

Answer (score 1):

`Graph.io()` and the now preferred Gremlin step `io()` use the `GryoReader` to read your file (unless the graph provider overrides the latter Gremlin `io()` step and I don't think that JansuGraph does). So, if you use `GryoReader` you typically end up needing a lot of memory (more than you would expect) because it holds a cache of all vertices to speed loading. Ultimately, it is not terribly efficient at loading and the expectation has been from TinkerPop's perspective, that providers would optimize loading with their own native bulk loader by intercepting the `io()` step when encountered. In absence of this optimization, the general recommendation is to use the bulk loading tools of the graph you are using directly. For JanusGraph that likely means parallelizing the load your self as part of a script or using a Gremlin OLAP method of loading. Some recommendations can be found in the [JanusGraph Documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/bulk-loading/) as well as in these blog posts:

https://medium.com/@nitinpoddar/bulk-loading-data-into-janusgraph-ace7d146af05
https://medium.com/@nitinpoddar/bulk-loading-data-into-janusgraph-part-2-ca946db26582

You can also consider a custom `VertexProgram` for bulk loading. TinkerPop has the [`CloneVertexProgram`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#clonevertexprogramusingspark) which is the more general successor to the [`BulkLoaderVertexProgram`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.5/reference/#_loading_with_bulkloadervertexprogram) (now deprecated/removed in recent versions) which had some popularity with JanusGraph as it's generalized bulk loading tool before TinkerPop moved away from trying to supply that sort of functionality.

At your scale of a few million edges, I probably would have wrote a small groovy script that would run in Gremlin Console to just load my data directly to the graph and avoid trying to go to a intermediate format like Gryo first. It would probably go much faster and would save you from having to dig too far into bulk loading tactics for JanusGraph. If you choose that case, then that link to the JanusGraph Documentation I supplied above should be of most help to you. You can save worrying about using OLAP, Spark and other options until you have hundreds of millions of edges (or more) to load.